# Where's the markdown reference?

Tags: support

Where's the markdown reference? I am not looking for keyboard shortcuts. It seems there's more than the icons. The FAQ page should have a link to it.

Comment: That **?** on the editor you mean?

Answer (score 7):

Click on the orange **?** button, that should bring up a link to advanced help.

[image]

That links takes you to: https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

If you are a new user, you won't even have to click on the **?** button; it's already expanded.

But I do agree that there should be a link to that page somewhere in the FAQ.